# How can I discover which exchange server I am getting the GAL from?

Tags: outlook, cache, exchange

In an environment with 2 exchange servers, and cached mode on, is there a way to determine which exchange server I am getting my GAL from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these 2 exchange servers running as a cluster or independent ? 
It should be whichever GAL is set to as the default for that outlook profile user.
In Powershell you can run Get-GlobalAddressList, if its version 2003 go to the ESM and navigate to recipient policies and check from there.